# Add category as filter in all other categories in layered navigation?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, layered-navigation

Is there any way to make a category appear in all other categories as the filter in layered navigation?

Comment: I assume you want a filter which, regardless of category listing, allows to filter by listed products which belong to one specific category?

Answer (score 0):

In admin `catalog->category management->your catagory->is anchor` set to **Yes** then save. After doing this you will have your **layered navigation** with `catalog_category_layered` layout handle.